# How to pass arguments in Powershell called from SQL Stored procedure

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to execute a power shell script from SQL Server.
Every thing works to me with Static value of passed arguments.
But when i tried with dynamic argument its not working.

following is the statement which I am trying:

```
declare @dteBatchDate as varchar(20)
set @dteBatchDate='2014-06-23 15:49:00'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe -c "get-service | D:\Listing1.ps1 -@dteBatchDate"'
```

I think it is a syntax issue. Can any body suggest solution regarding this.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
declare @dteBatchDate as varchar(20)
declare @sql as varchar(255)
set @dteBatchDate='2014-06-23 15:49:00'
set @sql = 'powershell.exe -c "get-service | D:\Listing1.ps1 -' + @dteBatchDate + '"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Comment: Thanks It works for me. with a slight change before Passing arguments no need to have '-' sign.

Comment: I just fixed the statement you provided. No way to check as I am here on my mobile ;-)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't accept parameters with spaces in between. How'd you do that?

Answer (score 5):

The way you are passing the variable to `xp_cmdshell` does not allow it to be rendered for PowerShell to see it. You are basically doing this from the view of a PowerShell prompt:

```
powershell.exe -c "get-service | D:\Listing1.ps1 -@dteBatchDate"
```

In the same manner when you need a variable rendered before the command is executed in PowerShell, you have to do the same thing with `xp_cmdshell`.

So building your command before you pass it to `xp_cmdshell`.
[image]

Comment: This is a good answer, as it explains what was the issue that *causes* the problem.